# How to create android.com like slideshow effect

Tags: jquery

Can anybody tell me what script google uses for their slideshow effects on their site http://www.android.com? The animations are very slick.

Comment: Most likely they're using their own script implemented in-house. They're Google after all.

Comment: have you tried looking at the source?

Comment: Yeah, that "cool effect" is chrome only...

Answer (score 0):

They are apparently using an in-house script, for Chrome it is `-webkit-transform: translateZ(value);` with a value transition combined with a CSS3 opacity transition and JavaScript change. It's fairly simple to make.

In Internet Explorer and Mozilla Firefox it is a simple fade effect. I haven't tested other browsers.

Comment: I don't have time to really get one together, but, here's a non-working one: http://jsfiddle.net/SO_AMK/aMW6G/

Comment: are you still working on it? If you finalize it, add it to your answer and it will be a nice little post for other people that are interested in this...

Comment: I really don't have the time right now to put it together, but you can look at the code and once you get it to parse the translateZ value it should work. You can look at the source from android.com for methods.